# How can I correct a typo with Apple ID?

Tags: itunes, apple-id

How can I use iTunes with an email address that isn't actually an email address?

Comment: Please edit your question to flesh it out a bit more.  Tell us more about what you're trying to achieve (what your goal is) and what you've tried.  Why do you want to use iTunes with an email address that isn't actually an email address?  Have you tried fixing the email address associated with your Apple ID?  What solutions/approaches have you considered and rejected?  See http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends. If you are using an apple email (such as me.com, iCLoud.com, mac.com, etc) then that email address is by default an apple id, and I don't know of a way to edit it.

If you are using a 3rd party email address (such as hotmail, gmail, yahoo, your own domain etc) as your appleid, then you should first TURN OFF FindMyIPhone on your device if it is enabled.  (DO NOT change your primary Apple ID with FindMyIPhone enabled, it can be enabled again as soon as you are done with the changes.)

Next navigate to http://appleid.apple.com and choose the "manage" option, then log in.  An "Edit" button will appear next to your primary appleid.  (if the Edit button does not appear then you are using an apple generated email address such as me.com, iCloud.com, mac.com etc.)

Next on your phone go to the settings app, and log out and log back in for iCloud, iTunes and App Store, iMessage, Facetime, Game Center, and update email accounts if needed).

Once everything is working as expected be sure to turn FindMyIPhone back on.  (It is possible to get out of the mess you create attempting to do this with FindMyIPhone turned on--i did it-- but it is much simpler to just turn it off before starting and re-enable it at the end of the process).

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I can see you getting out of this jam if [Tyson's answer on the normal method](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/180297/5472) fails you:

1. Contact your email provider and explain the dilemma. Say you'll need delivery of the "broken" email for several hours while you change the AppleID to be the correct email. That way you can receive the validation emails from Apple.
2. Contact Apple support and explain the dilemma. They might be able to see it's a new account and the mistake an understandable one and get engineering involved to make things right. They might also explain another way to recover or delete that account and let you start over.

Unless you have a gmail account where you can take advantage of things like punctuation and +this_extra text gets ignored. (if my email were bmike@gmail.com - I could use b.mike@gmail or b.m.i.ke@gmail and it would all go to my account. Again, this last idea is an oddball thing where you'd have to luck into the proper typo to have it work.

Comment: If the email address used as an appleid was not an Apple address (e.g. not me.com, not icloud, not mac.com, etc) It may be possible to change it via http://appleid.apple.com , click manage appleid, log in... if the edit button appears next to primary email address then you can change it.  If the edit button does NOT appear then you are using an apple email address, which by default is an appleid.

Comment: @Tyson Doesn't a change request get sent to the old email for verification before it becomes active?

Comment: When I changed mine recently the old address didn't exist anymore.

Comment: @Tyson Cool and thanks. That's a bonus if they let you authenticate with DOB/security theater questions/trusted device. I recalled getting an email, but perhaps that was an FYI you're no longer the email to contact support as opposed to a link in the process.

Comment: One thing you don't get a warning for is turning off findMyiPhone.  Before changing your apple id be certain to turn off findMyiPhone.  Once logged back into iCloud it can be turned back on.

Comment: @Tyson Could you edit my answer to have your solution as the best choice and then my two alternatives if the easy way doesn't work? Alternatively, please answer this so I can vote your information up.

Comment: As long as the password to the old appleid is known, I don't think there is a problem.  The problem comes when the old email no longer exists AND the appleid password also isn't known... surprisingly people think there is a magic answer to that when there is not (unless security Q and A's have been set).  I went ahead and added a diff answer.